# Class of all sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

I am reading a book Axioms and Set Theory - A first course in Set Theory by Robert André.
Here the auther writes as follows.

Let L = { x : set(x) }, By axiom of class construction L is a class of all sets.

Later he proves that L is a Proper Class. That is also fine.

Then he stated that elements of L are pure sets and every element x of set that belongs to  L is a set.

I need a proof for above statement.

Also he stated that x is a pure set if and only if y belongs to x belongs to L implies that y belong to L.

I need a proof that why elements of L satisfies this property.

Also want to know if set C = { 1 , 2 } is an element of L.
C is a set so should be an element of L (Class of all sets). But then all elements of L are pure sets and C is not a pure set. So I am confused.

Comment: How do you define "pure set"? Do you mean "set with no urelements"? Identify $0:=\emptyset,\,n+1:=n\cup\{n\}$.

Comment: Pure set is a set whose elements are also sets

Comment: If that's not synonymous with "set", what else could be elements of sets? Would it be urelements? What theory is Robert André using?

Comment: Until you say, within set theory, what "1" and "2" are, you can't assert that they are not sets. Traditionally,  $0=\varnothing$, $1 = \{0\} = \{\varnothing\}$, and $2=\{0,1\} = \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$. But the key is: you can just say "set $C=\{1,2\}$". You need to explicitly say what each thing is. You don't define things into existence, you have to prove they exist within your theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read this particular book before, and I think some clarification is required.

When discussing formal theories, it is important to state the language in which the theory is being presented. ZFC is a *first-order theory*, meaning that the language of ZFC is a type of *first-order logic*. The syntax of first-order logic, which is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Syntax), distinguishes between *logical* and *nonlogical* symbols, and identifies certain symbols as *terms*.

ZFC is a *pure set theory*, which means that all of its terms are *sets*, and there is one nonlogical symbol $(\in)$. You cannot *prove* that the class of sets contains only sets, or that the elements of every member of the class of sets is a set. Rather, the only objects in the language of ZFC are *defined* as sets.

In other set theories - [KPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory_with_urelements), for example - there are object called *urelements* which are not sets. These are not present in ZF set theory because such objects can be encoded as sets using a variety of techniques; the purely set-theoretic account of the natural numbers is explained in Chapter V. As explained there, the set $\{1,2\}$ is defined as $\{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$.

I would also note that *classes* are *not* objects in ZFC set theory. André's use of classes *extends* the usual axioms of ZFC. In standard ZFC set theory, proper classes like the class of all sets are merely "implied" rather than stated.

**Edit/Correction:**

André's explanation *does* treat classes and sets as objects, and provides that any element of a set is a set. So the proof of $y\in x\in L\implies y\in L$ is $y\in x\implies set(y)$.

Comment: In the book the OP reads, the author treats *classes* as its objects and *set* as yet another primitive (and defines the concept of *element* for any class that can appear to the left of $\in$). The axioms of extension and construction are formulated for classes, pairing for sets, comprehension/power/union/replacement for sets, infinity grants a set, and regularity is only about sets. It is not directly obvious that every *element* must be a *set*

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You're right, it is explained this way in the first chapter. Still, since the only other primitive object is "set," and a class cannot be an element, it stands to reason that any element of a set is again a set.

Answer (score 0):

In this set's theory,C={1,2} also can be written as C={∅,{∅},{∅,{∅}}},or any sets with 2 elements.

You said C is not a pure set, because you consider number in $R$,but in fact there is no relation between this 1 and this 2,can you add 1 and 2?No,you even dont define "add".

Comment: Please can u give me an example of set which is not a pure set and also an example of set which is pure set.

Comment: In ZFC axiomatic set theory system,any set is pure set.Do you remember why we defined Class?

Comment: Yes for that Russell paradox, hope I got this right. I think I have miss understood a lot of basic concepts.

Comment: @xxxxxllllllllxxxxx This should make us ask: Why does the author define the concept of *pure* set when it does not differ from the concept of set? To the point the OP asks about, the author has shown "All sets are elements" (Thm 2.7), but not (what he would now need) "All elements of sets are sets"